# C++: memory issue when using Spectra to compute eigenvalues

Tags: c++, memory, segmentation-fault, eigen

I'm using the library called `Spectra` to compute eigenvalues of an `Eigen` sparse matrix. The [sample code](https://spectralib.org/quick-start.html)  provided by the package says that we should do this:

```
// Construct matrix operation object using the wrapper class SparseGenMatProd
SparseGenMatProd<double> op(M);

// Construct eigen solver object, requesting the largest three eigenvalues
GenEigsSolver< double, LARGEST_MAGN, SparseGenMatProd<double> > eigs(&op, 3, 30);

// Initialize and compute
eigs.init();
int nconv = eigs.compute();

// Retrieve results
Eigen::VectorXcd evalues;
if(eigs.info() == SUCCESSFUL)
    evalues = eigs.eigenvalues();
```

In the code excerpt above and below, `M` is an `Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>`. However, my sparse matrix is really big and it would consume a lot of memory. Using the sample code leads to a segmentation fault. Therefore, I had to create the matrix operation object on the heap by doing:

```
SparseGenMatProd<double>* op = new SparseGenMatProd<double>(M);

// Construct eigen solver object, requesting the smallest three eigenvalues
GenEigsSolver< double, SMALLEST_MAGN, SparseGenMatProd<double> >* eigs = new GenEigsSolver< double, SMALLEST_MAGN, SparseGenMatProd<double> >(op, 3, 30);

// Initialize and compute
eigs->init(); int nconv = eigs->compute();
```

This, unfortunately, doesn't fix the issue. I still see a segmentation fault. I'm not sure if that's because my matrix `M` is too big and I should pass it by reference (if i'm not already doing it). If so, how should I accomplish that?

Comment: Use a debugger!

Comment: Not a solution, but this is why your "solution" does not make a difference: You are creating objects on the heap which (themselves) are only a few bytes large. The actual data was already allocated on the heap.

Comment: I'm the author of Spectra. How large and sparse is your matrix? And which step triggers the segfault?